# Can and/or should we be able to link directly to other answers in other questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

Is there a mechanism to link or cross reference a specific answer from a perhaps related or unrelated question.

If not, what should the interface be like? And should this be a feature?

It seems that questions are the atomic unit of StackOverflow. Are there any strong arguments for making Answers an atomic unit. And how could/should the reputation system account for this? If someone writes up a particular strong answer to a generic question, wouldn't it be useful to correlate the answer to other questions even if it is not a direct, albeit useful, answer?

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15827/stackoverflow-etiquette-reusing-other-peoples-past-responses/15828#15828

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below each answer, there is a "link" link which is a permalink to that answer. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the link reference. I guess I didn't notice that. But also, what I was wondering was more a process question. Basically a way for questions to auto reference related answers. When someone asks a broad question: "What is a pointer?" perhaps the system could be smart enough to suggest possible answers based on the question at hand but would be the result of answers to other questions. Basically an efficient way to repurpose in depth answer where possible.

Comment: You have the **Related** list on the right side that tries to suggest related posts. I think that will provide enough intelligence for this. It is kind of an overkill to try to automatically propose answers from other posts like you suggest, because that will require a structure on the answer that is not possible to achieve, I think.